# A word for a 'paper bag with a handle'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is there any word for a paper bag with a handle?

What I mean by 'a paper bag with a handle' is that the bag has a part to grip on top of it so you can carry it.

Comment: I don't know of any special word for it. I would refer to it in exactly the same way you did: _paper bag with a handle_. If there's a special word for it, I couldn't find it at [this website](http://www.webstaurantstore.com/15973/paper-shopping-bags-with-handles.html).

Answer (score 1):

To me, the term *paper shopping bag* comes to mind. This indicates the material it is made of, and its purpose, to facilitate shopping.

[image]

<sub>(image taken from PSDGraphics)</sub>

Comment: I usually call these "handle bags", as opposed to paper shopping bags that do not have handles. But that might just be me (AmE).

Answer (score 0):

It is also known as a **paper tote** which is short for "paper tote bag".